# SaveFileDialog event FileOk

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    SaveFileDialog Sdialog = new SaveFileDialog();  
    Sdialog.ShowDialog();
    Sdialog.FileOk += Sdialog_FileOk;            
}

void Sdialog_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {            
        StreamWriter FileProtocol = new StreamWriter(((SaveFileDialog)sender).FileName);
        FileProtocol.Write(textBox3.Text);
        FileProtocol.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("File is write ok");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Unknown Error. File is not write");
    }
}
```

Why does event FileOk not work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you need to hook the event up **before** calling `ShowDialog()`. When you call `ShowDialog()` it **stops** processing on that thread and **waits** for a response.

So, instead of this:

```
Sdialog.ShowDialog();
Sdialog.FileOk += Sdialog_FileOk;
```

do this:

```
Sdialog.FileOk += Sdialog_FileOk;
Sdialog.ShowDialog();
```

---

To use the `DialogResult` to simplify you're workflow, just do this:

```
if (Sdialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    try
    {            
        StreamWriter FileProtocol =
            new StreamWriter(Sdialog.FileName);
        FileProtocol.Write(textBox3.Text);
        FileProtocol.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("File is write ok");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Unknown Error. File is not write");
    }
}
```

**ALSO:** instead of doing this:

```
StreamWriter FileProtocol =
    new StreamWriter(Sdialog.FileName);
FileProtocol.Write(textBox3.Text);
FileProtocol.Close();
```

how about simplify it to this:

```
File.AppendAllText(Sdialog.FileName, textBox3.Text);
```

The benefit is two fold:

- The code is clearly much more concise, and;
- The code is safer because it manages the un-managed resources appropriately for you.

Comment: But then I see a message (MessageBox.Show("File is write ok");) on top of the window to save the file.

Comment: @mega7star, well that's because that event is fired while the dialog is still open (or closing). You don't need a `MessageBox` in there. Just do you're work. On the other hand you could simply just grab the `FileName` from the `SaveFileDialog` if the `DialogResult` of `ShowDialog` is `DialogResult.OK`.

Comment: @mega7star, please see my edit showing you how to leverage the result of the `ShowDialog()`.